# Counting Partial Matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumproduct

I have a column of numerical data that is less than or = to 10 digits long.

I then have a second set of data (SKUs) that each have a 10 digit numerical value assigned.

I need to count, for each of the digits in the first column, how many SKUs have a 10 digit value that begins with those numbers.

For example:

Table 1

| Value | Count(Calculation) |
| --- | --- |
| 870899 | 0 |
| 94031000 | 2 |
| 94032000 | 1 |

Table 2

| SKU | SKUVALUE |
| --- | --- |
| AAA111 | 9403100090 |
| AAA222 | 9403100000 |
| AAA333 | 9403200000 |

Im trying to calculate the second column in table 1.

94031000 has 2 hits, SKU AAA111 and SKU AAA222, because both begin with 94031000

I tried initially with a countif and wildcards, but ran into problems where because they arent text, it wont work.

I was trying then to use sumproduct, but im calculating 0 for all rows just like when I tried to use countif.

My attempt looks something like this:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(Table2SKUVALUE,LEN(Table1A1))=A1))

Or for a more specific formula but with less context:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(F:F,LEN(A139))=A139))

I was basically trying to say where the value in the VALUE column was = to the value in SKUVALUE column, only to the number of digits in the VALUE column.

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: @ScottCraner this returns a 0 for a value I can see more than 0 of. Reading elsewhere, this has something to do with it not working on numbers

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH([@Value]&"*",Table2[SKUVALUE]))))`

Comment: @P.b I added a screenshot after attempting this one, and every single value returned a 68.

Edit: my calculations were set to manual...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDDMi.jpg it works when I do it. Is it number values other text?

Comment: @P.b yeah its working. Like I said I realized my calculations were set to manual for some reason.